# totaling OTU from 2 or more observations and assign to new observation in OTU table from qiime

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequencing, microbiome

I am new to microbiome processing pipeline but I want to ask, How do I combine two observations and assign it to a new single observation in the OTU table resulted from QIIME.

Here is the situation. I am doing river microbiome analysis. I have water sample named A-P, P for particle-attached sample and A for its and A-F for free-living sample for the same site. They are just different in the filter size being used.

I extracted the DNA, sequenced, and processed the raw reads separately using QIIME for all the 110 samples. But now, I am doing analysis on "R" and i need to combine A-F and A-P as one observation, namely only A. It seems simple to do on "R" for only one observation. But, I have 110 observations needed to be merged to 55. Are there any simple ways doing that without doing it one by one either in "R" or QIIME

Thanks,
Bob Adyari

Comment: There is no word "wanna" in English. I have changed it to "want to" in your question.

Comment: Which is the output you are working on from QIIME? is it biom-format?

Comment: sorry for the long missing. I figured it out already in a bit complicated way. So, I ran collapse_samples.py in qiime to merge two samples to one new. Thanks anyway